# c# windows form - How received td area data in my textbox or listbox?

Tags: regex, split, streamreader, htmlelements

your boss name after finish b tag Want received random generated name so we need this name in our textbox or list box area.

Actually every loading time we see your boss name after coming new name so we just received name in our textbox area or list box are.

Please help me how I am received name data in my list box or textbox Please.

> ```
>  
>        
>          Your boss name  adriana
>          your id: 2241
>          Email: yourbossemail@gmail.com
>          File Format: officeial
> ```

> ```
>  
>        
>          Your boss name  jennefer
>          your id: 2241
>          Email: yourbossemail@gmail.com
>          File Format: officeial
> ```

```
my code 

HtmlElementCollection bColl = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("td");
        foreach (HtmlElement bEl in bColl)
        {
            if (bEl.GetAttribute("b").Contains("your"))
            txtLinkDetails.Text = bEl.OuterHtml.Split('"')[3].Replace("&amp", "&");
        }
```

Comment: what is your input output?

Comment: <table>
       <tbody><tr><td><b>Your boss name </b> jennefer</td></tr>
       <tr><td><b>your id:</b> 2241</td></tr>
       <tr><td><b>Email:</b> yourbossemail@gmail.com</td></tr>
       <tr><td><b>File Format:</b> officeial</td></tr>
     </tbody></table>
     </td>

Answer (score 2):

**Try this:**
at  first you find innerhtml of table then filter by `<b>([^<]+)<\/b>([^<]+)` regex

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jX1qW8/1)**

And you will get following output with array group:

```
//example
//group 1 =Your boss name
// group 2= jennefer
```

[image]